# Building regex to catch word

Tags: java, regex, string

Been trying to solve this problem for a few days now and just can't see what's incorrect about it.

The idea of the function is to catch spam mail and as such it takes as parameter an email to be checked and a string array containing words to be checked against and build a regex out of all the words. Then using the built regex strings check the body and subject of the email if it contains any of the words, if it does it shouldn't post it.

It catches the spam mails that I have tried but it also catches all other mails.

```
private boolean isSpam(Mail mail, String[] filter){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Build the regex String for each string in filter
    for(int i=0;i<filter.length;i++){
        sb.append("(?i).*");
        for(int ii = 0;ii<filter[i].length();ii++){
            sb.append("[" + filter[i].charAt(ii) + "\\s]*"); // [x\\s]*; x = current letter
        }
        filter[i] = sb.toString();
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
    }

    for(int i=0;i<filter.length;i++){
        if(mail.getSubject().matches(filter[i]) ||  mail.getMessage().matches(filter[i])){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The regex string for ex. **spam** would look like: **(?i).*[s\\s]*[p\\s]*[a\\s]*[m\\s]***

Comment: Are you checking for each character ?

Comment: Are you trying to essentially do a case-insensitive substring for several words? As written, that regex will match "      ".  I have a feeling what you want is more like (?i)spam1|spam2|spam3.

Comment: @David Ehrmann I am but I also want it to detect occurrence of these word if they contain white spaces or duplicate letters. Why exactly does my current regex match " " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write (?i).* , it matches for every character (case-insensitive) that occurs zero or more times.

Lose the .* .

Now if the first string in your filter is spam and you have the word s am, it will match it because you have your regex as (?i)[s\s][p\s][a\s][m\s].So it looks for an occurence of p or white space between s and a.

So lose the \s.

The * at the end of each character suggests that you are looking for the regex expression to occur 0 or more times. So even if the word doesnt exist, it will retrun true.

so, (?i)[s\s]* [p\s]* [a\s]* [m\s]* would mean that you want the word to match even if it has 0 or more occurrences of s followed by 0 or more occurrences of p followed 0 or more occurrences of a followed by  0 or more occurrences of m.

So lose the *

In the end your regex to match for the word spam in every mail that contains the word should be,

(?i)[s][p][a][m]  -- case insensitive s followed by p followed by a followed by m

Read more [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

**EDIT**

Maybe this works as per the requirements.

```
(?i).*[s]+[\\s]*[p]+[\\s]*[a]+[\\s]*[m]+[\\s]*.*
```

Comment: Whops, forgot to mention some of the specifics: I want it to detect the words even if it contains duplicate letters or white spaces.

Comment: so if the mail has these words "Crisp A    MASAS" and "Crisspp AAAA    MMMMASAS".. should it match spam ?

Comment: Yes, far from a good filter but that's what I'm going for at least.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a Profanity checker that looks like this.  If some text contained any profanity, it was rejected

```
public Map<Boolean, String> TextContainsProfanity(String adText,Pattern filter) {
    Boolean profanity = false;
    Map<Boolean, String> results = new HashMap<Boolean, String>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Matcher m = filter.matcher(adText);
    sb.append(" : ");
    while (m.find()) {
        sb.append(m.group()); 
        sb.append(" ");
        profanity = true;
    }
    results.put(profanity, sb.toString());
    return results;
}
```

The regex string for bad words looked this this:

```
\bBAD\b|\bTERRIBLE\b|\bOFFENSIVE\b
```